# Extjs 4 FiltersFeature blur in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, filter, extjs4

I have a problem with Extjs 4.0.2.
When I move out mouse from textfield in filter (Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature), I can't enter text in this field. This problem appears in Chrome, but in FF all OK.
I want to continue entering the text in filter field, while my mouse out of it.

Comment: My version is ext-4.0.2a

Comment: Why don't you start by using last stable 4.0.7?

Comment: The start of my project was at last summer, so I don't want to change version because of the possibility of new bugs